# Error "Unable to resolve reference of exec"

Tags: java, jar, mule

Estoy creando un dataweave dentro de un transform en Mule 4. Desde aquí estoy tratando de ejecutar un jar ejecutable mediante comando. A dicho jar le tengo que pasar por parámetro un archivo (un path donde se ubica). En la cmd el comando sería algo así `java -jar WordToPDFTransformation.jar example.docx`.

El problema es que me salta el error *"Unable to resolve reference of exec"* en el dw cuando intento realizar exec. El dataweave que estoy usando es:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::Runtime
var path = (carpeta donde está el archivo)
var fileName = (nombre del archivo)
var rutaJar = (ruta del jar)
output application/java
---
exec("java -jar " ++ rutaJar ++ " " ++ path ++ fileName)   //salta el error en exec
```

No sé si se realiza así el comando a ejecutar.

Comment: y cual es exactamente le mensaje de error que te "salta"?

Comment: @RuslanLópez Está en el título, "Unable to resolve reference of exec" :)